# Adding a column to a dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
some_info   THIS_info
abd          set_1
def          set_1
www          set_1
qqq          set_2
wws          set_2
2222         set_3
```

and another dataframe like this

```
THIS_info   this_algo
set_1        algo_1
set_2        algo_2
set_3        algo_2
```

I want to add a column to the first dataframe, based on the info on "THIS_info" so that I can get

```
some_info   THIS_info  this_algo
abd          set_1      algo_1
def          set_1      algo_1
www          set_1      algo_1
qqq          set_2      algo_2
wws          set_2      algo_2
2222         set_3      algo_2
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function to join the two dataframes (df1 and df2):

```py
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='THIS_info')
print(df1)
```

Output:

```py
some_info   THIS_info  this_algo
abd          set_1      algo_1
def          set_1      algo_1
www          set_1      algo_1
qqq          set_2      algo_2
wws          set_2      algo_2
2222         set_3      algo_2
```

Note that parameters `how` and `on` are optional in this example, but are useful in a more general situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function, like

```
import pandas as pd

df_left = pd.DataFrame({
    "some_info": ["abd", "def", "www", "qqq", "wws", "2222"],
    "THIS_info": ["set_1", "set_1", "set_1", "set_2", "set_2", "set_3"]
})
df_right = pd.DataFrame({
    "THIS_info": ["set_1", "set_2", "set_3"],
    "this_algo": ["algo_1", "algo_2", "algo_2"]
})
df = df_left.merge(df_right, on="THIS_info", how="left")
print(df)
```

Then you can get output:

```
  some_info THIS_info this_algo
0       abd     set_1    algo_1
1       def     set_1    algo_1
2       www     set_1    algo_1
3       qqq     set_2    algo_2
4       wws     set_2    algo_2
5      2222     set_3    algo_2
```